# Interface that supports Task or Task <TResult> in one method

Tags: c#, api, generics, task, factory-pattern

I am writing an API which uses the factory pattern.

I have an interface:

```cs
public interface IAbstractProduct<TRes, TCom>
{
    Task<TRes> ExecuteAsync(TCom command);
}
```

Task returns `TRes`, but sometimes I'd like to just return `Task` without `TResults`.
Is it possible to insert a `TRes` such that `Task<TRes> = Task`?

Or use some other way to make the interface `IAbstractProduct` handle `Task` and `Task<TRes>`?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? A Task<T> is a Task already. The two types are as different as `Action` and `Func`, or a `void` method with one returning a value. Sure, you can call any method but you can only retrieve results from functions.

Comment: They're different things, just as a method returning void is not the same as a method returning a string. Why do you want to treat those the same?

Comment: Maybe it's better to have a two overloads of methods with different return types?

Comment: In the .NET Core code you'll find an internal `Void` class used to make methods act like functions. It's easier to create a function that returns nothing or `Void` than it is to create something that makes both methods and functions behave the same.

Comment: Please explain what the issue is here, you can do `Task t = abstractProduct.ExecuteAsync(...)`. `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`.

Comment: I suspect the real problem isn't how to make `ExecuteAsync` work in both cases - just return `Task`. The problem is how the *caller* is going to handle the result - does it try to retrieve a result or not? Will it have to cast or not? What does the caller do? How are `IAbstractProduct` and `ExecuteAsync` used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ultimately. What you *could* do is:

- for reference-types (if you can add `where TRes : class`), perhaps return a `Task<TRes>` where the result is `null`
- for value-types (if you can add `where TRes : struct`), return a `Task<TRes?>`

But: if `TRes` could be *any* type, then no: this is not possible. In that scenario, you could consider something like `Task<(bool HasResult, TRes Result)>` - effectively a manually constructed optional type.

Comment: But what TRes should the caller supply when they're not interested in the return value or when there is none (i.e. when ExecuteAsync will ignore TRes anyway)? Object? Better to not pass it then anyway.

Comment: Or use a `Void` or `Unit` as a return type. .NET Core does this behind the scenes

Comment: As for `(bool HasResult, TRes Result)`, although I use this, it gets ugly real fast. Same with any attempt at a Maybe<> or Result<> with the current state of C#. We really, really, really need DUs for this.

Comment: @Magnus there's nothing `just` about nulls (for reference types) or clean objects (for value types). That's worse than `(bool,result)`